# Changing the layout of an Excel Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

A little help will be deeply appreciated. I have a database whose layout is not convenient for me. Here is the layout:

[image: Inconvenient Layout]

I would like the sections within the FINANCIAL column to become headed columns themselves. I would also like a single column DATE under which i will put all the dates(2020, 2019, 2018, etc). My database is very large and I'm looking for the fastest way to do it. Here is an illustration of the layout I'm trying to get:

[image: Preferred Layout]

Comment: The fastest way to do it would be if you did actually have a database. You have a spreadsheet.

Comment: How many years' worth of data do you have? That'll make the difference between some manual copy/paste solution vs. using Visual Basic to re-build your table.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I start with:

[image]

I select any cell in that range and use Data>From Table/Range. After clicking OK, I have a query in the Power Query Editor:

[image]

I select the first three columns, then use Transform>Unpivot columns>Unpivot other columns:

[image]

Now I have this:

[image]

I select the financials column and use Transform>Pivot column. I configure it like this:

[image]

After clicking OK, I have this:

[image]

Now I just click Home>Clost & Load to return the result to the workbook.

[image]

You can reposition the columns in the Power Query editor by dragging them to your preferred positions.

When new data are added to the source, you can just right-click the result in the worksheet and choose "Refresh" to re-run the query.